# Git Blame in a one-developer project... how to get branch and comment instead of author name?

Tags: git

Using Git Blame in a one-developer project, the "author" is always the same person. It would be useful to be able to see instead, which branch and comment introduced each line of code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git blame` tells which commit introduced a line, but it's a mystery which branch did it. A commit could be reachable from multiple branches. Git does not have a reliable record of on which commit a branch is created and it could be removed after being merged to another branch. `git blame` works in a local repository and the repository may not have all the branches.

If you mean `commit log` by `comment`, this solution may meet your need.

```
git blame --line-porcelain <path> | grep -e '^\s' -e '^summary' -e '^[0-9a-f]\{40\}'
```

`--line-porcelain` prints lines of detailed information of a line of code. `^\s` matches the line of code, `^summary` matches the subject of the commit log, and `^[0-9a-f]\{40\}` matches the commit that introduced the line of code.